# Device(Android) back button click detection using Ionic2/angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am able to detect the device(Android) back button click event using the following code. But after clicking the back button, it is going **one level back** and opening the confirmation dialog.

**How do i avoid this behavior(going to the previous screen) using ionic2?**

```
registerBackButtonListener() {              
        document.addEventListener('backbutton', () => {           
            let backBtnCnfirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
              message: 'Do you want to close the App?',
              buttons: [
              {
               text: 'Yes',
               handler: () => {
               this.platform.exitApp();
              }
            },
            {
             text: 'No',
             handler: () => {
            }
          }
        ]
       });
        backBtnCnfirm.present();
        }, false);
    }
```

Comment: When are you calling `registerBackButtonListener()`?

Comment: i am calling inside platform.ready() function

Comment: present your alert in a method called `ionViewWillLeave()` this will be executed before your  page is `popped` let me work it into an answer

Answer (score 0):

The back button will call `navCtrl.pop()`, so going back to the previous page. Ionic offers lifecycle events such as viewDidEnter, viewWillEnter, viewWillLeave etc.

When in your code you create this function:

```
ionViewWillLeave(){
   this.alertCtrl.create({
     message: 'Do you want to close the App?',
              buttons: [
              {
                text: 'Yes',
                handler: () => {
                  this.platform.exitApp();
               }
             },
             {
              text: 'No',
              role: 'cancel'
            }
           ]
   }).present();
}
```

Ionic will execute this before the `navCtrl.pop()` has been executed.

Note: this will execute **every** time the page will leave (so when pushing or popping manually) but I think you're smart enough to find a workaround (boolean check f.e.)

*(I don't know your requirements but I find it bad UX to show such a message when the backbutton is pressed, usually people would want to go a page back)*